# CakePHP LEFT JOIN on multiple tables with condition

Tags: mysql, cakephp, left-join

I want to use this CakePHP form to do a LEFT join. See [CakePHP Book - section on Joining Tables](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'channels',
        'alias' => 'Channel',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Channel.id = Item.channel_id',
        )
    )
);
$Item->find('all', $options);
```

EXCEPT that my LEFT JOIN has a dependent table with conditions. In MySQL the join looks like this

```
LEFT JOIN (
    channels as Channel 
        INNER JOIN regions as Region ON ( Region.id = Channel.region_id and Region.id=1 )
) ON Channel.id = Item.channel_id
```

Can I do the same thing in CakePHP 2.0 using the `$options['joins']` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bit of fiddling, I discovered this does the "trick" in CakePHP. According to SQL EXPLAIN, this is a much faster join than using a sub-query to force conditions on the LEFT join table

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => '(channels as `Channel` INNER JOIN regions as `Region`
                      ON ( `Region`.id = `Channel`.region_id and `Region`.id=1 ))',
//        'alias' => 'Channel',  // the alias is 'included' in the 'table' field
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Channel.id = Item.channel_id',
        )
    )
);
$Item->find('all', $options);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$options['joins'] = array(
array('table' => 'channels',
    'alias' => 'Channel',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => array(
        'Channel.id = Item.channel_id',
        'Region.id' = 1

    )
  )
);
$Item->find('all', $options);
```

The condition key in joins options can work too

Comment: no, that's wrong. you still have to add the Region table to the join, and if you add it separately, then you have to give it a separate LEFT/INNER join type. you get a different result. You could add Region together with Channel in a sub-select, but that is a much slower query.

Comment: And contain() with models associations?

Comment: there is a miss place of single quotation inside conditions array. there should be 'Region.id = 1'      ****not 'Region.id' = 1

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but for those who will see this through google like me you should try the following.

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'channels',
        'alias' => 'Channel',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Item.channel_id = Channel.id'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'regions',
        'alias' => 'Region',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Channel.region_id = Region.id',
            'Region.id = 1'
        )
    )
);
```